# Fetching and comparing common likes between two profiles using Facebook API

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, api, match

I need to fetch and compare commom page likes or another data from facebook between different profiles.

For example, using Tinder, when you are reading about the profiles you can see your common page likes, that's it!

Does anyone has some information about it?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes

> A user access token with user_likes permission is required to see all pages liked by that person.

You need to read the user likes of both profiles and match them on your own.

Keep in mind that you need to go through a [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) process for `user_likes`.

Comment: Thanks! But to be more specific I need to compare between two profiles the common likes.

Comment: as i wrote: "You need to read the user likes of both profiles and match them on your own." - store them in your database and compare them.

Comment: Great! Tks a lot! @luschn